# PyDev: How to avoid "assignment to reserved built-in symbol: id"?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I have PyDev 5.6 (for Eclipse). I'm getting "assignment to reserved built-in symbol: id" warning for the `id`:

```
class bla(object):
    def myfn(self, task):
        id = task['id']
```

I found #1457 Bogus "Assignment to reserved built-in symbol" warnings
(https://sourceforge.net/p/pydev/bugs/1457/)
but it's for PyDev 2.3 and issue should be fixed in 2.6.0

I don't want to disable all "Redefinition of builtin symbols" in Code Analysis (it's possible in Preferences). Someone suggested to use `Id` or `_id` instead of `id` , but for me the `id` is variable and I want to keep it in lower case.

Is it possible to set Eclipse/PyDev to ignore this symbol?

Currently it's in class and it's used locally inside func "myfn" (or other).
But I would like to ignore it also on "main" level. If you work w/ databases, 'id' is everywhere :)

I'm new in Eclipse and PyDev. Maybe I overlooked some setting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What @S.Ahmad said, is correct, you can ignore it with comments in the code (and use PyDev itself to help you there).

Another option would be disabling that check altogether (for all variables) in `PyDev > Editor > Code Analysis > Others > Redefinition of builtin symbols` (there's no option to disable it just for `id`).

Personally, I try to stay clear from redefining builtins such as you're doing (even `id`) and give it a more meaningful name when assigning to a local (i.e.: in your example I'd call it `task_id`, not only `id`), and it's usually straightforward to define it, as the `id` is usually related to `id` of something (IMHO, it also makes code clearer to follow later on if you give the `id` more meaning).

Comment: The `id` has good meaning as primary key in DB table. For me it's strange meaning if `id()` returns some address. If this is something specific to built-in things in Python, it would be better if they use something like `__id__()` but this is out of scope of this question.

Comment: As a note, the id in the table is always bound to the table... If you have an id in a class, PyDev will also not complain, it'll only complain if you override the pre-defined `id` builtin from Python (i.e.: when you put it as local or parameter in a function).

Answer (score 1):

Select/Highlight the variable and then press Ctrl+1.

Choose `@ReservedAssignment` from the dropdown menu. This will suppress the warning.

Or you can simply paste `# @ReservedAssignment` after each variable to suppress the message.

I don't think we can suppress such messages for a variable globally but I could be wrong.

Comment: This is not answer to my question b/c it's for 1 occur only.
I would like to set it for whole Eclipse/PyDev or at least once per file, something like
`#@UnreserveSymbols=id`

Answer (score 0):

Now I found out that id(var) is func returning address of variable/object. Hmmm... maybe that's reason for this warning.

I did little research:

```
>>> a= 2
>>> a
2
>>> type(a)
<class 'int'>
>>> id(a)
1650106848
>>> a.__str__
<method-wrapper '__str__' of int object at 0x00000000625AA1E0>
>>> "{:02x}".format( id(a) )      ### hex( id(a) )
'625aa1e0'                        ### so it's address
>>> type( id )
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> id = 1
>>> type( id )
<class 'int'>
>>> "{:02x}".format( id(a) )      ### id() doesn't work now
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>>
```

How dangerous can be to do `id = something` and destroy `id()` functionality?

Comment: The danger comes from using `id` thinking it was `id` from your object and by mistake using the builtin `id` and vice-versa. Personally I try to stay clear from it (see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43453424/110451)